# Laravel broadcast message to pusher

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher

I am attempting to broadcast a message via pusher in laravel but I am getting the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError · Too few arguments to function 
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::{closure}(), 1 passed in 
    laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php on line 77 and exactly 2 
    expected routes/channels.php:33App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::{closure}    
});
```

The code that it's occuring on is the following

```
Broadcast::channel('conversations.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return $user->inConversation($id);
});
```

I have another channel and it works fine

```
Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function ($user, $id){
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Not sure why there are too few arguments

*** UPDATE ***
I'm using laravel livewire.

The event class is as follows:

```
class MessageAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param Message $message
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'message' => [
                'id' => $this->message->id
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('conversations.' . $this->message->conversation->id);
    }
}
```

The laravel livewire function is as follows:

```
public function reply()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        $message = $this->conversation->messages()->create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'body' => $this->body
        ]);

        $this->conversation->update([
            'last_message_at' => now()
        ]);

        foreach ($this->conversation->others as $user) {
            $user->conversations()->updateExistingPivot($this->conversation, [
                'read_at' => null
            ]);
        }

        broadcast(new MessageAdded($message))->toOthers();

        $this->emit('message.created', $message->id);

        $this->body = '';
    }
```

Regards
Danny

Comment: Can you add event class and controller?

Comment: Can you `dd($message);` before `broadcast(new MessageAdded($message))->toOthers();` in livewire

Comment: it looks like conversation id is not being passed.

Comment: this is the data

"user_id" => 1
    "body" => "fff"
    "conversation_id" => 1
    "updated_at" => "2020-08-03 19:15:59"
    "created_at" => "2020-08-03 19:15:59"
    "id" => 16

conversation_id is set

Comment: sorry for the late, regarding data structure above, I think `$this->message->conversation->id` should be `$this->message->conversation_id` in `BroadcastOn` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the solution here was to set the Broadcast::routes in the BroadcastServiceProvider to the following

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth']);
```